# getContent show only token instead of data in Controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-5

I have form which sends array of objects in json format using ajax. But when I do $request->getContent I only get the token. It seems I don't even send data, could you help me?

***my form in createPage.blade.php***

```
<form action="/invoices/submitInvoice" method="post" id="my-form">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   HERE IS MY TABLE STRUCTURE CODE
   <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
<button onclick="myCreateFunction()">Add</button>
```

***my sending logic in sendGood.js***

```
let counter = 0,
    nameContainer = [],
    priceContainer = [],
    obj = {},
    objArr = [];
$(function(){
  $('#my-form').submit(function(e){
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll("#my-form input[type=text]");

    //Just loop over inputs and gather values
    for (let i = 0, element; element = elements[i++];) {
      if(element.type === "text"){
        if(element.value){
          if(element.className === "goodName") 
            nameContainer.push(element.value);
          else 
            priceContainer.push(element.value);
        }
      }
    }

    //Push to object array that going to be sent via ajax
    for(let i = 0; i < nameContainer.length; i++){
      obj.name = nameContainer[i];
      obj.price = priceContainer[i];
      objArr.push(obj);
      obj = {};
    }

    let route = $('#my-form').data('route');
    $.ajax({
      type : 'POST',
      url : url('/invoices/submitInvoice'),
      data : {dataInput : JSON.stringify(objArr)},
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      dataType : 'json',
      success: function(Response){
        console.log("daw",Response);
      }
    });
    e.preventDefault()
  });
});
```

***InvoiceControllerWeb.php***

```
public function invoiceCreate(Request $request){
   dd($request->all());
}
```

***Result***

```
^ array:1 [▼
  "_token" => "hEfjKsDHZadG3G5fCIgEJWcrNrFpv6G4PtjUPzJA"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found solution. My route was wrong. I changed "action" to "data-route" then inside data-route I put route helper in my ***createPage.blade.php***.

```
<form data-route="{{ route('company::invoices::makeInvoice') }}" method="post" id="my-form">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   HERE IS MY TABLE STRUCTURE CODE
   <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
<button onclick="myCreateFunction()">Add</button>
```

Then in my ajax I put route variable to url.

```
let route = $('#my-form').data('route');
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : route,
    data : {dataInput : JSON.stringify(objArr)},
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(Response){
    console.log("daw",Response); 
  }
});
```